# Image Upload Improvement Request: Reduce Clicks Required to Link Images

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, uploader

Can the "Insert an image" dialog be improved by automatically focusing in the upload-url input field when "from the web" is clicked?  As it stands now, "from the web" must be clicked, followed by a second click to focus the input field.

[image: 2 clicks for the price of 1!]

I know this sounds small. But over on the [Graphic Design beta](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) I spend a bit of time editing posts to move image links from external sources to stack.imgur (to prevent linkrot).  This improvement would remove some unnecessary friction from that process.

*UPDATE:*
Thanks to animuson's comments, I have been made aware that some browsers focus on the "from the web" button and the input field can be selected with a Tab and not require a second click.  2 thoughts on that...

1. This does not work the same across all supported browsers.
   It works as described in IE (tested 9.0.8112) and FF (tested 9.0.1), but not in Chrome (tested 16.0.912), Opera (tested 11.60), or Safari (tested 5.1.2).  I'm not sure if this warrants filing a bug question.
2. This still requires multiple interactions to get the same result that could/should be achieved with 1 interaction.

Comment: You could technically eliminated click #2 there by simply hitting the `TAB` key after clicking "from the web".

Comment: @animuson You would think, however clicking "from the web" actually focuses the cursor on the page.  Typing a `TAB` focuses the search box.

Comment: Weird, it works fine for me in Firefox. It focuses the link "from the web" and hitting TAB goes to the next item which is the box below it.

Comment: @animuson Updated the question in response to your comments.  Even if the `TAB` worked consistently, it still requires extra input that should be eliminated.

Comment: Little addition: maybe it should also "remember" your last selection meaning if you chose "from the web", this will be the default next time you open the insert image dialog.

Comment: Personally I'd like to paste an image directly into the post body, but that's just me being lazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fair point, and easy enough. Added to the next build.