# Change the toolbar's image dialog to pickup selected image link

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

When editing posts where users have placed links to images on third party sites (usually because they haven't attained the rep to insert images themselves) I find myself embedding the image and repeating the same process which could be improved a bit. The current process is:

1. Highlight the URL to the image in the post.
2. Copy it (right click, ctrl+c, etc.).
3. Click the image icon in the editor toolbar.
4. Click the "From the web" radio button.
5. Paste the URL (right click, ctrl+v, etc.).
6. Click the 'add picture' button.
7. <strike>Profit</strike>.

We could save two whole steps (#2 and #5) if the image dialog automatically took the text that was highlighted in step one and populated the "From the web" input field. This improvement is along the lines of [Image Upload Improvement Request: Reduce Clicks Required to Link Images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119269/image-upload-improvement-request-reduce-clicks-required-to-link-images).